# Finding FFT coefficients from FFT or RFFT in Python

Tags: python, fft

I want to use the sum of first five fft coefficients as a feature for a classifier (in Python language). I tried a few resources but I can't get a grasp of this concept. For example, I have an array of 10 elements.

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] # Lets say, it represent discrete values of the x-axis of an accelerometer
```

if I apply fft in Python to this array, I get the following output:

```
array([ 16.00000000+0.j        ,   0.50000000-5.34306783j,
        -3.73606798-0.36327126j,   0.50000000+1.98786975j,
         0.73606798-1.53884177j,  -2.00000000+0.j        ,
         0.73606798+1.53884177j,   0.50000000-1.98786975j,
        -3.73606798+0.36327126j,   0.50000000+5.34306783j])
```

if I apply rfft (real fft) in Python to this array, I get the following output:

```
array([ 16.        ,   0.5       ,  -5.34306783,  -3.73606798,
        -0.36327126,   0.5       ,   1.98786975,   0.73606798,
        -1.53884177,  -2.        ])
```

***How can I calculate the the sum of first five coefficients from these two outputs?***

In case of rfft:
Should it be just the sum of absolute values of the first five values?

Comment: `16.00000000+0.j` is ~= to `16.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Can someone explain the difference between these two outputs? Shouldn't `rfft` just display the real part of the fft?

`rfft` efficiently computes the FFT of a real-valued input sequence whereas `fft` computes the FFT of a possibly complex-valued input sequence. If the input sequence happen to be purely real, `fft` will return an equivalent output, within some numerical accuracy and packaging considerations. More specifically for the packaging, `rfft` avoid returning the upper half of the spectrum which happens to be symmetric when computing the FFT of a real-valued input. It also avoids returning the imaginary part of the DC (0Hz) bin and of the Nyquist frequency (half the sampling rate) bin since those are always zero when dealing with real-valued inputs.

So, the output from `fft.fft` of your example can be mapped to the following outputs of `fft.rfft`:

```
16.00000000+0.j         -> rfft[0]        
0.50000000-5.34306783j  -> rfft[1], rfft[2]
-3.73606798-0.36327126j -> rfft[3], rfft[4]
0.50000000+1.98786975j  -> rfft[5], rfft[6]
0.73606798-1.53884177j  -> rfft[7], rfft[8]
-2.00000000+0.j         -> rfft[9]
```

> 2. How can I calculate the sum of first five coefficients from these two outputs? In case of `rfft`: should it be just the sum of absolute values of the first five values?

As observed from the different packaging of the outputs, the first 5 complex-valued coefficients of `fft.fft` correspond to the first 9 floating point values returned by `fft.rfft`. To compute the sum you will have to compute separately the sum on the real parts and on the imaginary parts. So, for the sum of the first five coefficients this would give you something like:

```
A = np.fft.rfft(a);
sum_re = A[0] + A[1] + A[3] + A[5] + A[7];
sum_im =        A[2] + A[4] + A[6] + A[8];
```

Comment: Thanks. However, if I am using rfft then should add all ten elements to get the sum of first five fft coefficients? As the amount of information contained in the first five complex coefficients is now spread over the ten real coefficients. Is this correct ?

Comment: The information contained in the first five complex coefficients is now spread over **9** real coefficients. The imaginary part of the first coefficient will always be 0 so it is omitted in the output of `rfft`. Also when you compute the sum, you should compute the sum on the real and imaginary part separately.

Comment: Are you sure about adding real and imaginary parts separately for rfft? Shouldn't we call all these coefficients real now? I think it should be just the first five coefficients. Moreover, it should be absolute values of these coefficients for its summation.

Comment: "Shouldn't we call all these coefficients real now?" No, they represent complex numbers even though they are not returned as `complex` data type. Whether you should sum the absolute values depends on your application, but if you were going to add the complex coefficients of the standard FFT output (which should give you `14-5.25731111j` for your example), then you should add in the equivalent way when dealing with `rfft`'s output. If on the other hand you wanted the sum of magnitudes, then you'd sum the `sqrt` of the pairwise sum of squared real and imaginary parts.